# GCP: Change the timezone of the SQL instance in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a simple question I just want to change the timezone of the `SQL instance` that I have created in the `google cloud platform`. Now I know questions like this has been asked before but the suggestion works for `MYSQL instance`

One of the solution that I found is to change the `default_time_zone` flag, this also works fine but for the MYSQL instance not in SQL instance and I am working in SQL instance there is no such flag for SQL instance.

**So is there any way to change the timezone of the SQL instance ?**

```
May be some flag or some sort of query or command that can change the time zone of the SQL server.
```

**Steps that I follow for creating a SQL instance.**

1. Go to SQL page.
2. Click **create instance.**
3. Click to the **SQL Server.**
4. Enter the instance ID and password.
5. **Region:** us-central1(lowa).
6. Choose private IP under connection section.
7. And leave rest as a default.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart

Answer (score -1):

The [default](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#default_time_zone_for_vm_instances) time zone for your VM instance is Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) but you can change this time zone in your instances.

If you instance is working on Linux you can change the default time zone in this instance with the following commands:

```
sudo -s

dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Here you can see how I configured it:

```
$ date
Thu Sep 17 19:04:17 UTC 2020
$ sudo -s
root# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

[image]

```
Current default time zone: 'Europe/London'
Local time is now:      Thu Sep 17 20:06:10 BST 2020.
Universal Time is now:  Thu Sep 17 19:06:10 UTC 2020.

$ date
Thu Sep 17 20:06:19 BST 2020
```

You can use this [link](http://andrewcmaxwell.com/2014/07/how-to-change-the-timezone-on-google-cloud-debian-virtual-machines) as reference.

But if you are working in a WIndows VM Instance you must open the timezone settings via `Server Manager`
[image]
And then you can select the new timezone.
[image]
At this point you will see the changes in `Server Manager`
[image]

Comment: really thank you for replying but my SQL cloud instance is not either linux or windows machine its different database the provided by GCP. I am more over looking for flag that can change the time zone or some sort of query or command that can change the time zone.

Comment: Could you please share with me the command or steps you are using to create your instance?

Comment: Yes sure I update the question added the step that I follow to create the sql instance using GCP console.

Comment: Your last update helped me to understand well what do you need to achieve, Unfortunately this option **IS NOT** available in GCP. But there is a Feature Request  for Google https://issuetracker.google.com/144531368 to allow users to change time zones in Server SQL, you can follow up the progress of this request or  comment there.

Comment: @DhirendraSaw if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!